# How to uglify JS/HTML/CSS in a client side react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, react-router, obfuscation

I'd like to know how to obfuscate a website build using the create react app project. (Rest assure the purpose for obfuscation is merely obfuscation itself and not any misguided sense of security).

Is there a way to use the popular uglify JS library in the build pipeline of the react app? How does it interact with various react features? What about dynamic imports? As of right now, there's almost no reliable literature on the matter anywhere else so I'm wondering if this can be done at all.

What about obfuscating CSS? (Random class names) Or is it possible to obfuscate generated HTML? (by randomizing div nesting)

Comment: Production build is not enough?

Comment: Not really, production builds still preserve things like variable and method names. Ideally, I'd like complete obliteration of everything related to my code. (e.g: Things named a1, a2, b1 etc). For crash reporting, it should ideally have a method of generating a mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJS is already a part of the react build process when you run 'react-scripts build'. You are able to disable sourcemaps when you run this build process, if you don't want others being able to read your code straight away, although it can be run through external programs into an easy to read manner.

If you want more control over the build/pipeline process, you will have to use a bundler. There are multiple out there such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). Here is a short [guide](https://blog.sqreen.com/how-to-build-test-and-deploy-react-applications/) I found after a quick search. I hope this information helps.

Comment: The index.html file is not minified, neither are any assets, nor is CSS. Any idea how to integrate their minification into the build process without ejecting?

Comment: Here is a [guide](https://deliciousbrains.com/npm-build-script/) that should provide something similar to what you are looking for, if you want to avoid using a bundler, although it is not optimal.

Comment: I know about using manual npm scripts, but I'm specifically looking for a solution that bundle nicely with CRA. This is really a task that should be plug and play, that should work for everyone, all use-cases, just like how uglifyJS works, but for everything. I can always eject or write down dozens of minifications scripts for my use case specifically but that's not really the scalable or generic solution I'm looking for